# Django sending context to multiple views

Tags: django, post, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to achieve following tasks in Django:

1. First page: User fills a large Job application form and that data is
   sent to Second page
2. Second page: User reviews his previously filled data and proceeds to third page
3. Third page: User pays the amount(came from Second page) and once paid, then only all this data is saved to DB.

I've done First page work of filling form and then sending that data to Second page.

Here's my **views.py**

```
def applyJob(request,id=None):
        job = get_object_or_404(AddJob, id=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            context = {
                'jobName': job.jobName,
                'jobID' :  job.pk,
                'cfName' : request.POST.get('candidateFirstName'),
                'cmName' : request.POST.get('candidateMiddleName'),
                'clName' : request.POST.get('candidateLastName'),
                ......
                return render(request,'reviewAppliedJob.html',context)
        else:
            context ={
                "jobName": job.jobName,
                "id": id,
            }
            return render(request,'applyJob.html',context)
```

Since I'm sending the context data using `return render(request,'reviewAppliedJob.html',context)`, URL is not changing and so it's not going to my **reviewAppliedJob views** and so I cannot write code to go to Third page.

```
def reviewAppliedJob(request):
    return HttpResponse('done....')
```

For that, I can use `HttpResponseRedirect('/reviewAppliedJob')` instead of `render` in `applyJob()` but it will not send my context data. Django allows sending context either using **render(), messages framework, url params or session**. But since I have large amount of data, I don't know which one to use and will work perfectly.

What's the best way to achieve this task efficiently and securely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) instead. Instead of writing three individual views you can write one. After user fills the data, save them in a session key with a phase key temporarily. In this way, when the view is processed you can access to data and phase of the user.

Comment: Okay. Sessions are a great way to store data as far as I know. But I wanted to know that whether it's a good practice and secure to store large amount of data in Sessions?

Comment: Well, sessions are stored in server side, so we can say it's secure; otherwise we wouldn't keep authentication information in the session. For data size, I suggest you expire the session data after 15 mins, (depends on how much information is given) so that it wouldn't cause too much load. If you really don't want to store all the data in sessions, you can create a model for temporary data and store them with expiration date, then you only have to include the object id in the session.